# На с#, ошибка, не удаётся преобразовать из double в int

Tags: c#

```
if(textBox1.Text == "" || textBox2.Text == "") MessageBox.Show("Are you on drugs?");
            Random rnd12 = new Random();
            double v = rnd12.Next(Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text), Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text));
            textBox3.Text = $"{v}";
```

Comment: Уточните, какую именно задачу вы решаете, что и в каком формате задается в текстбоксах и почему именно double вам нужен?

Comment: Попробую угадать `int v = rnd12.Next(int.Parse(textBox1.Text), int.Parse(textBox2.Text));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю, нужно сгенерировать случайное число между двумя double. А метод rnd12.Next работает только с int.

Решение лежит на англо-stackoverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17786771/random-double-between-given-numbers

Код будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
  if (textBox1.Text == "" || textBox2.Text == "") MessageBox.Show("Are you on drugs?");
  else {
    NumberFormatInfo nfi = new NumberFormatInfo();
    nfi.NumberDecimalSeparator = "."; // указываем разделитель для конвертации
    double value1 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text, nfi);
    double value2 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text, nfi);
    Random rnd12 = new Random();
    double random = rnd12.NextDouble();
    double v = value1 + (random * (value2 - value1));
  }
```

Comment: MessageBox.Show("Are you under the drugs?");

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!